# apply_along_axis with 2 arguments varying for each 1d slice

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to optimize code that currently uses nested for loops & calls scipy's functions.

Basically, I have a first function that calls scipy's find_peaks() methods, and then I want to interpolate those data points (the peak) to find a function that describes them. For example, I first find the peak. This basically is a 2D array of dimension 25*30 (axis 0) with 1000 elements in each (axis 1).

```
arr = np.random.rand(25,30,1000)
arr = arr.reshape((arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2]))
# we have a 25*30 set of 1000 pts each. find peaks for that
peaks = np.apply_along_axis(find_peaks, 1, arr, height=0,)
```

Find peaks returns something of the form:

```
peak_indices = peaks[:,0]
peak_values = peaks[:,1]["peak_heights"]
```

So far so good. That's essentially the (x,y) coordinates of the points I want to interpolate.

Now, I want to interpolate those couples of indices-heights values to obtain some function, using scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d(...). Interp1d's signature is of the form:

```
interp1d(x, y, kind='linear', axis=-1, copy=True, bounds_error=None, fill_value=nan, assume_sorted=False)
```

Where x would be my peak_indices, and y my peak_values.

The question:

How can I pass to this function 2 arguments that vary with each slice? E.g. in other words, my first use of apply_along_axis only used a single slice-dependant argument (the 1000 points for each of my 25*30 elements of axis 0). However here I need to pass to the function TWO arguments - the peak_indices & the peak_values. Can any pythonista think of a clever way to unpack those arguments AFTER I pass them to apply_along_axis as tuples or something? Kind of:

```
arr=*[peak_indices, peak_values]
```

I cannot really edit the interp1D function itself, which would be my solution if I was going to call my own function...

EDIT: part of the benefits of using apply along axis is that I should get performance improvements compared to nested ifs, since numpy should be able to bulk-process those calculation. Ideally any solution should use a notation that will still allow those optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the idea that `apply_along_axis` is a performance tool?  Does it actually work faster in this case?

```
arr = np.random.rand(25,30,1000)
arr = arr.reshape((arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2]))
# we have a 25*30 set of 1000 pts each. find peaks for that
peaks = np.apply_along_axis(find_peaks, 1, arr, height=0,)
```

compared to:

```
peaks = np.array([find_peaks(x, height=0) for x in arr])
```

That is a simple iteration over the 25*30 set of 1d arrays.

`apply` does a test calculation to determine the return shape and dtype.  It constructs are `result` array, and then iterates on all axes except 1, and calls the function with that 1d array.  There's no compiling, or "bulk processing" (what ever that is).  It just hides a loop in a function call.

It does make iteration over 2 axes of a 3d array prettier, but not faster:

You could have used it on the original `arr`, to get (25,30,2) result:

```
peaks = np.apply_along_axis(find_peaks, 2, arr_3d, height=0,)
```

I'm guessing `find_peaks` returns a 2 element tuple of values, and `peaks` will then be an object dtype array.

Since `apply_along_axis` does not have any performance advantages, I don't see the point to trying to use it with a more complex array.  It's handy when you have a 3d array, and a function that takes a 1d input, but beyond that ....?